# I'm trying to test "mayastor" on k8s and i need to install Kernel module 'nvme_tcp`

Tags: kernel, apt, kvm, microk8s, package-management

However, i have the following issue :

```bash
sudo microk8s enable core/mayastor
Checking for HugePages (>= 1024)...
Checking for HugePages (>= 1024)... OK
Checking for nvme_tcp module...

Kernel module 'nvme_tcp' is missing or not loaded. For Ubuntu, enable with:

    sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
    sudo modprobe nvme-tcp
    echo 'nvme-tcp' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules-load.d/microk8s-mayastor.conf

Note that the 'nvme_tcp' module is needed in all cluster nodes.
```

and when i try to install :

```bash
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1073-kvm
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1073-kvm'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1073-kvm'
```

This is the current system :

```bash
Linux microk8s01 5.4.0-1073-kvm #78-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 8 07:53:42 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever "apt-get install" shows errors that it can't find something, it's a clue that you may need to run

"sudo apt update"

Comment: I did, still the same result.